# Conditional Expectation and Indicator variable

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, almost-everywhere

**Question**

Assume that for integrable random variables $X$ and $Y$ we have $E(X|Y)=Y$ and $E(Y|X)=X$.

Show that for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$0\leq E[(X-Y)1(Y\leq x< X)]=E[(Y-X)1(X>x,Y>x)]$
$0\geq E[(X-Y)1(X\leq x< Y)]=E[(Y-X)1(X>x,Y>x)]$

Conclude that $X=Y$ a.s.

PS: 1 stands for indicator variable

**Attempt**
Pick $x\in \mathbb{R}$

\begin{align}
E[(X-Y)1(Y\leq x\leq X)]&=E[X1(Y\leq x<X)]-E[Y1(Y\leq x<X)]\\
                         &=E[X1(Y\leq x<X)]-E[Y1(Y\leq x<X)]\\
&=E[X1(X>x)]-E[Y1(Y\leq x)]\\
&=E[X1(X>x)]+E[Y1(Y>x)]\\
&=E[X1(X>x)]+E[Y1(Y>x)]\\
&=E[(X+Y)1(X>x,Y>y)]
\end{align}

Clearly i did something wrong? Any thoughts/hints? I don't even understand where i could use the assumptions..

**Edit**

In the post [Show that $X = Y$ almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272308/show-that-x-y-almost-surely?rq=1) he show how to prove $X=Y$ a.s. from our assumptions.

Comment: $y$ is also arbitrary?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary yes.

Comment: I mean the little $y$ in the two "Show that" questions

Comment: It's supposed to be an x. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $E[X|Y]=Y$ almost surely and $E[Y|X]=X$ almost surely then $X=Y$ almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666843/if-exy-y-almost-surely-and-eyx-x-almost-surely-then-x-y-almost-surel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think $X=Y$ a.s. can be proved simpler by properties of conditional expectation(CE). You see CE is basically $L^2$-projections, so the condition roughly says $X$ after two projections remains the same. Since projection is shrinking in $L^2$ sense, this implies the following:

\begin{align*}
    EX^2 &= E\left(E\left[E[X\mid Y]\mid X\right]\right)^2\\
        &\leq E[E[(E[X\mid Y])^2\mid X]] \\
        &= E[(E[X\mid Y])^2]\\
       &\leq EX^2,
\end{align*}

so the equality by Jensen implies $Y=E[X\mid Y]=X$ a.s. on $\sigma(Y)$. Similarly we can conclude $X=Y$ a.s. on $\sigma(X)$, and we are done.

As for the approach suggested in context, note that $$1(X>x\geq Y)=1(X>x)-1(X>x,Y>x),$$

so basically for the first equality you only need to show $$E[X1(X>x)]=E[Y1(X>x)].$$

This is easily done by the condition given: $$E[Y1(X>x)]=E[E[Y \mid X]1(X>x)]=E[X1(X>x)].$$

Comment: That $X = Y$ when they both belong to $\mathscr{L}^2$ is relatively easy as one only needs to expand out $E((X-Y)^2)$ by conditioning on $X$ and on $Y.$ However, when $X$ or $Y$ do not belong to $\mathscr{L}^2,$ but only $\mathscr{L}^1,$ then you need to do other tricks.

Comment: I see. That makes sense.

Comment: In fact, out of my memory, the proof of the $\mathscr{L}^1$ case, I don't know. I've seen it here in MSE but I don't recall right now.

Comment: I think I just wrote it in OP's manner which works in $L^1$ case. I would admire if you could check whether it is correct.

Comment: That is correct, $\{X > x\}$ is $X$-measurable, so $E(X \mathbf{1}_{\{X > x\}}) = E(Y \mathbf{1}_{\{Y > x\}})$ by definition of CE.